# How to update UIView before next method is called in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to update my textView on screen before it starts downloading data.  Right now, it only updates the view after all of the downloads are complete.  How can I do it before or in between the downloads?

**Edit**:  I want the `self.textView.text = @"Connection is good, start syncing...";` to update the UI before the downloading starts.  But right now, it only updates after the download finishes.

Here is what the code looks like.

```
if ([self.webApp oAuthTokenIsValid:&error responseError:&responseError]) {
    self.textView.text = @"Connection is good, start syncing...";
    [self.textView setNeedsDisplay];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadCustomers:) withObject:error];
}
```

I'm new to this and have yet to learn how threads work, but from what I read, the downloadCustomers function should be using a background thread leaving the main thread to update the UI.

Comment: Tried like update the UI into seperate method([self updateTextView]) which needs to execute                                  self.textView.text = @"Connection is good, start syncing...";        using main thread.

Comment: I think that what @wesley meant was: UI elements must be updated on the main thread, so if the updating function is running in the background, your UI won't be updated (use GCD or performSelectorOnMainThread).

Comment: What's currently happening, using the code as you have it with the above snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([self.webApp oAuthTokenIsValid:&error responseError:&responseError]) {
    self.textView.text = @"Connection is good, start syncing...";
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      [self downloadCustomers];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Do whatever you want when your download is finished, maybe self.textView.text = @"syncing finished"
      });
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks iVishal. This works and is a good start for me to start learning about these things.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern here is to initialize your download on background thread and then call back to main thread for UI update.

Below is an example using *GCD*. The advantage of *GCD* version is that you can consider using whatever you do in `-downloadCustomers`, to insert in-line where you call it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   [self downloadCustomers];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.textView setNeedsDisplay];
      });
});
```

Comment: OP wants to update his textview before download starts. I guess your code will update the textview after downloading will be finished.

Comment: OP assumes that his code updates textview after download completes, but that is not so. The code he posted does update UI immediately regardless whether download has completed or not. If he needs to update UI in between downloads, he needs to split up the downloads and update UI after each individual pieces has completed.

Comment: read the question again carefully , he is not assuming but his code is actually updating the UI after download is finished, so your code and his code are doing same thing.And besides he is updating his textview with string "Connection is good, start syncing..." which I dont he would like to show after the download is finished.

Comment: @iVishal You are right. I could not see it even when I had looked twice at it. Now I see it.

Comment: @iVishal, after all you used my answer and added a couple of lines from OP's post :)